# Importing table from CSV file in MSSM, rows are omitted but not showing, file is stuck

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import

I imported a table from a CSV file. The preview showed the right data and the columns are all the same. The procedure looked succesfull as 4 rows were omitted. But when querying the Table it is empty.

I cannot try it again because the file is in use. Also when i try bulk insert i get the following message.

> Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "C:\Users\PWAdmin\Documents\Balansen\balh.csv" could not be opened.
>   Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server Authentication. If so, does SQL Server have access to the folder? That's usually why the error pops up. Right click the folder, go to security, and give the SQLServer access.